# Using enquire.js - media queries calling jQuery

Tags: media-queries, enquire.js

I'm trying to use enquire.js in a project to control jQuery with media queries I have a jquery slideshow that I want to start when the window is wider than 500px.

I'm using this code in load_Gallery.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 500px)", function() {

          ///slideshow code here

        }).listen();

    });
```

I'm calling load_Gallery.js in the head of the page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/load_Gallery.js"></script>
```

I have downloaded enquire.js here -

https://raw.github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/master/dist/enquire.js

I copied this to a txt file and named it enquire.1.4.1.js in my js folder with other js files.

I'm not calling this file like other js files in the head of the document, should I be calling it in the head?

Am I doing something wrong - any advice.

Comment: enquire author here! basically order the inclusion of your scripts like this: jquery, enquire and then your file load_gallery. also you should always put your scripts at the bottom of the page, as close to the closing body tag as possible - this causes the page to be rendered quicker and gives perception of better load time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you been to http://jquery.com/ and downloaded the file and connected this to your script?

Comment: Downloaded which file - query.js ?